# Refresh redis cache on DB change

Tags: redis

I've got a stored procedure that loads some data (about 59k items) and it takes 30 seconds. This SP must be called when the application starts. I was wondering if there's a reasonable way to invalidate the Redis cache entry via SQL ...any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it from your SQL, do the invalidation / (re)loading to Redis from your application. 
The loading of this data into your application should be done by a separate component/service/module/part of your application. So that part should have all the responsibility of handling the needed data, including (re)loading it into the app, invalidating and reloading into Redis and so on. 
You should see your Redis server as an extension of your application cached data and not of your sql server data. That's why you should not link your relational database to your Redis. If you are going to change how you save this data into Redis that should not affect the SQL part, but only the application, and actually only the part of your application specialized with this.